# Issue creating a regular file for a directory

Tags: linux, files, touch

I have tried this but it is not working

```
touch dir_practice ../cambridge/library/ 
touch dir_practice  ./sample_dir/cambridge/library/****
```

[image]

Comment: What does “it is not working” mean?  Explain how you know something did not work, and what you expect instead.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) for `touch`, you'll see that it takes a filename as an argument. So what you need is:

```
touch ../cambridge/library/dir_practice
```

Since you're new to this, let's break this down. A relative pathname is a path specified relative to your current location. Contrast this with an absolute pathname, which starts from the root (/).

So you start at `sample_dir/oxford`. The first `..` takes you back to the `sample_dir` directory. Then, you want to go to the `library` directory, which is inside the `cambridge` directory. Inside the `library` directory, you want to create the file named `dir_practice`.

Put all that together, and you get `../` + `cambridge/library/` + `dir_practice`. Together, that's `../cambridge/library/dir_practice`. This is the argument we pass to the `touch` command.